# passing data from form to search method of controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I 've a search box where user will input the name of the users and the name will be searched in database data and if found display in tabular form.
But the value is not passed to the search method from the search page.

view page block

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('UserController@search')}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>User Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="100" minlength="3" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" required="required" name="UserName" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>        
                        </div> 
                    </div>                       
            </div>
    </form>
```

controller code block

```
public function searchDev()
    {
        return view ( 'pages.UserSearch');
    }

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $UserName = $request->input['UserName'];

    return response()->json($UserName);
    return response()->json('hello world');

    if($UserName != ""){
        $User = User::where ( 'NAME', 'LIKE', '%' . $UserName . '%' )->get (['id','NAME','CONTACT','TEMP_ADDRESS']);
        if (count ( $user ) > 0)
        {
            return view ( 'pages.UserSearch' ,compact('User'));
        }  
    }
}
```

In `search` method the json response is blank.

route code

```
Route::get('/UserSearch','UserController@searchDev');
Route::post('/UserSearch','UserController@search');
```

table structure image
[image]

Comment: Can you dump the contents of request?

Comment: change $request->['UserName'] to $request->UserName;

Comment: it should be object instead of  $UserName = $request->input['UserName']; this to  $UserName = $request->UserName;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrieving An Input Value**
Using a few simple methods, you may access all of the user input from your  `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance without worrying about which HTTP verb was used for the request. Regardless of the HTTP verb, the input method may be used to retrieve user input:

```
$UserName = $request->input('UserName');
```

or

```
$UserName = $request->UserName;
```

Refer 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: I am facing problem with eloquent query too. This query is not returning anything. Please help!!!

Comment: @nischalinn.can you add it by typing since i  cant view image in my system

Comment: NAME VARCHAR(150) utf8mb4_unicode_ci, this is the search field. Thank you!

Comment: @nischalinn.looks like every think good.just echo $userName as well as $User

Answer (score 1):

On the `request` object, `input` is a method not an array.

To access the form data you should do:

```
$request->input('UserName');
```

For more information on retrieving retrieving input from the request object please refer to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#retrieving-input)